# Circuit Representation of an Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, function, cryptography, boolean

I am trying to implement the idea found in this paper:

http://crypto.stanford.edu/craig/easy-fhe.pdf.

However, I do not know how the compute the circuit representation of an algorithm.

Suppose I have a function that takes a list of exactly 32, 32 bit signed integers, and returns a 64 bit signed integer representing the sum of the integers. How can I convert this function to a Boolean function? That is, I need to design a circuit where each output wire is a boolean function of the ands/ ors/ and nots of the 1024 input wires.

Notice that the function will take a fixed width input and produce a fixed width output.

Are there any techniques from electrical engineering or math that I can use?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you just want to design an "Adder" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29), what does this have to do with the paper?

Comment: No; yes, I am fully aware that it is simple to design an adder.

Comment: That function was just one SIMPLE example of any arbitrary function. Have you read the paper? If so, you will find that the FIRST and one of the KEY steps in the paper is to take the function you are interested in computing and converting it into the "circuit representation of f". How do I do this?

Comment: @user: I've not read the entire paper no, but, from a glance, it doesn't "need" to be in a circuit representation; it's just useful for the type of analysis the paper does. A circuit representation is the low-level way of showing a funciton (as they say, in AND/OR/NOT gates, or any universal set of gates). Because they are universal, they can determine any function. If you want to implement the algorithm described in the paper in code, you wouldn't do it at the circuit level, you'd understand how it works, and apply it at a higher level to what you are interested in. It's a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the logic in an [FPGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FPGA).  I think this will help you get an idea of the kind of circuit needed to sum exactly 32 32-bit inputs into a 64-bit output.

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

oh like u dude , u r the first person who gave me complete and gud answer, thanks *